# App not updating on developer console when stagerollout to 100%

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-install-apk, developer-console

We have published out app on playstore with 10% stage rollout & after few fixes uploaded newer apk with stage rollout as 100%. But its not updating and its more than 24hrs. We're currently on Advanced Mode which shows fig.1

We have wrote mail to develper support. But no response till date.

[image]

Do I need to deactivate the previous version?

Any help is highly appreciated.

We have contact there support but after a level 1 response, there is broken communication.

**Edit:** Its 4th day in the row. But still no effect as such.

Comment: You may need to wait a bit longer.

Comment: @SaeedSharman I'm worried because this is first time I've to wait for 24hr+. Prior we've our app published within fews hours(2-4)max.

Comment: @SaeedSharman any update?

Comment: nitesh, are you using the advance mode (I had the same issue when I tried to submit a new prod version, and I had one in Beta Testing), I just switch back to the simple one and all work properly. I think is and Google Play issue.

Comment: @MariaMercedesWyssAlvarez I cannot switch to simple mode since we have two apk in the prod which won't allow or I have to deactivate the previous apk to go to simple mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally after 15 days of patience google gave us a reason to simile :-)
Few key points that need to be taken care:

1. Make sure your app is compliant with new Google [Data and Privacy Policy](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/)
2. If you're using any third party library, make sure that its not using any user information like emailId without user consent.
3. Try to escalate the issue with google support team with chat or email, to know what exactly is the apps status.

At last if nothing helps. Be patient to get google support reply. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you go ahead and just deactivate the one that you don't want live anymore, you're not losing anything. The developer console will act up in cases where you might lose users etc. Sadly the documentation on the whole staged rollout feature is not as comprehensive as it should be. But rest assured, you can't really go wrong or break anything.

Comment: Its being close to 6 days. Google support answer are not at all satisfactory. So only option we think is same as yours, deactivate the current version that didn't gone live and upload a new version with higher version code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try going through the different steps on how to set up and maintain a staged rollout then follow the step that best suits you as provided in the Developer Console Help - [Release app updates with staged rollouts](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149#resume_new).

Aside from that, carrying out the given **tips for live staged rollouts** might prevent encountering issues related to releasing app updates with the use of staged rollouts.

> - While a staged rollout is in progress, you won't be able to update your production configuration. Before you can update your production configuration, you need to publish the staged rollout to 100% of users.
> - We recommend updating your Store Listing after your staged rollout reaches 100% of users.
> - During a staged rollout, it's a good idea to closely monitor crash reports and user feedback. Users receiving the staged rollout can leave public reviews on Google Play. Learn how to view your ratings & reviews with the Developer Console.
> - **You can update a staged rollout without halting by following the steps under [resume a staged rollout with a new APK](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149#resume_new).**